# Raster to ASCII tool in ArcMap returning different max and min values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, ascii

I am using Raster to ASCII conversion tool in ArcMap 10.7.1, and the issue is reproducible in 10.6.1, and 10.8.1.

I have two raster files in TIFF format.

When I used the tool for one raster the output .asc file returned the exact max and min values as that of the raster, but for another .tif the converted .asc file returned inaccurate max and min values.

The correct input and output converted .asc

[image]

Here we can see the difference in the max and min values

[image]

The issue seems to be data specific, but is the deciding factor the radiometric resolution or something else?

Comment: Check Properties on your original layer for the max and min. What you're seeing in your screenshots might just be the max and min of the color stretch, not the underlying data.

Comment: @ycartwhelen, The properties also reflect the same max and min values.

Comment: try running calculate statistics tool?

Comment: @Hornbydd, Thank you, Calculating Statistics and Building Pyramids does give the exact min and max value, but what could be the reason that for my other tif file it directly gave us the output, I also tried checking the option of building statistics and pyramids in the env settings of the tool, it does not retuned the desired output, I have to perform another step.

Comment: This option is not in environment settings. Try arcgis options tasters.

Comment: @FelixIP, the option to Calculate Statistics is not available in ArcMap Options--> Raster.